# Hyperledger fabric: Querying implicit data collection

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am seeing this when querying data from implicit private data collection.
Please see code snippet below.

When I query individual key (**using QueryBidPrivate/GetPrivateData**), I get corresponding data.
But if I query the complete collection (**using GetPrivateDataByRange(collection, "", "")**), I get nothing from the Iterator.

**peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n govtcontract -c '{"function":"QueryBidPrivate","Args":["100", "1035"]}'**
{"bidamt":100,"biddate":"2022-05-04","contractid":"1035","salt":"4567ab4567","vendorid":"100"}

**peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n govtcontract -c '{"function":"ListAllBids","Args":[]}'**

> No output

Is there anything I am missing here ?

```
// ListAllBids returns all Bids details from private state
func (s *SmartContract) ListAllBids(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface) ([]VendorBid, error) {
 
        // Get client org id and verify it matches peer org id.
        // In this scenario, client is only authorized to read/write private data from its own peer.
        clientOrgID, err := getClientOrgID(ctx, true)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to get verified OrgID: %s", err.Error())
        }
 
        collection := "_implicit_org_" + clientOrgID
 
        BidIterator, err := ctx.GetStub().GetPrivateDataByRange(collection, "", "")
        if err != nil {
                logger.Infof("ListAllBids error: %s", err.Error())
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to read bid list : %s", err.Error())
        }
        if BidIterator == nil {
                logger.Infof("ListAllBids : null iterator ")
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("bid private details does not exist ")
        }
        defer BidIterator.Close()
        logger.Infof("ListAllBids in govtcontract: no error")
 
        var allbids []VendorBid
        myMSPID, err := ctx.GetClientIdentity().GetMSPID()
        logger.Infof("myMSPID: %s", myMSPID)
        for BidIterator.HasNext() {
                logger.Infof("Iterator has element: ")
 
                entrybid, err := BidIterator.Next()
                if err != nil {
                        return nil, err
                }
 
                var bidvar VendorBid
                err = json.Unmarshal(entrybid.Value, &bidvar)
                if err != nil {
                        return nil, err
                }
 
                allbids = append(allbids, bidvar)
                logger.Infof("Iterator element: %s", entrybid.Value)
 
        }
        
 
        return allbids, nil
 
}

=========================================

// QueryBidPrivate returns the Bid details from owner's private data collection
func (s *SmartContract) QueryBidPrivate(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, vendorId string, contractId string) (string, error) {
 
        // Get client org id and verify it matches peer org id.
        // In this scenario, client is only authorized to read/write private data from its own peer.
        clientOrgID, err := getClientOrgID(ctx, true)
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to get verified OrgID: %s", err.Error())
        }
 
        collection := "_implicit_org_" + clientOrgID
 
        bidconkey, err := ctx.GetStub().CreateCompositeKey(vendorId, []string{contractId})
 
        bidDetails, err := ctx.GetStub().GetPrivateData(collection, bidconkey)
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to read bid private properties from client org's collection: %s", err.Error())
        }
        if bidDetails == nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("bid private details does not exist in client org's collection: %s", contractId)
        }
 
        return string(bidDetails), nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetPrivateDataByPartialCompositeKey()` is the function for querying a range of private data that was stored using a composite key. GetPrivateDataByRange() won't retrieve the data stored with a composite key.  I think in the above code snippet you have to replace the function call `GetPrivateDataByRange(collection, "", "")` with `GetPrivateDataByPartialCompositeKey(collection, vendorId, []string{})`

Sample usage can be found [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/cad6b90383d195bf4bc101fb67e431c1082422af/asset-transfer-secured-agreement/chaincode-go/asset_transfer_queries.go#L117GetPrivateDataByPartialCompositeKey).

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I could use GetPrivateDataByPartialCompositeKey and get it working. btw, I also saw a related thread here:
https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/85330623#10293
I still need to explore if this has any impact in my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error in the smart contract. The issue here is because of storing data on the composite key.
Instead of below code :

> ```
>          for BidIterator.HasNext() {
>             logger.Infof("Iterator has element: ")
>
>             entrybid, err := BidIterator.Next()
>             if err != nil {
>                     return nil, err
>             }
>
>             var bidvar VendorBid
>             err = json.Unmarshal(entrybid.Value, &bidvar)
>             if err != nil {
>                     return nil, err
>             }
>
>             allbids = append(allbids, bidvar)
>             logger.Infof("Iterator element: %s", entrybid.Value)
>
>     }
> ```

Use the below function

```
    func constructQueryResponseFromIterator(resultsIterator    shim.StateQueryIteratorInterface)
```

(*bytes.Buffer, error)
{

```
// buffer is a JSON array containing QueryResults
var buffer bytes.Buffer
buffer.WriteString("[")

bArrayMemberAlreadyWritten := false
for resultsIterator.HasNext() {
    queryResponse, err := resultsIterator.Next()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Add a comma before array members, suppress it for the first array member
    if bArrayMemberAlreadyWritten == true {
        buffer.WriteString(",")
    }
    buffer.WriteString("{")
    //buffer.WriteString("{\"Key\":")
    //buffer.WriteString("\"")
    //buffer.WriteString(queryResponse.Key)
    //buffer.WriteString("\"")

    buffer.WriteString(", \"Record\":")
    // Record is a JSON object, so we write as-is
    buffer.WriteString(string(queryResponse.Value))
    buffer.WriteString("}")
    bArrayMemberAlreadyWritten = true
}
buffer.WriteString("]")

return &buffer, nil
```

}

Comment: When I query  BidIterator, err := ctx.GetStub().GetPrivateDataByRange(collection, "#", "~"),   loop condition resultsIterator.HasNext() itself fails

Comment: BidIterator, err := ctx.GetStub().GetPrivateDataByRange(collection, "#", "~")  Do not pass special character. instead of that just pass empty string("")

Comment: when I used empty string "", for some reason, I do not get any values.
theres something specific to composite key usage.